# Proper usage of "From abc to xyz" with multiple nouns

Tags: nouns, commas, clauses, lists

Here is an example sentence:

"All of my interactions with the community, from the movie that I watched with Joe in his office, to Robert's engaging recitation about songwriting, to my hallway discussions with current members, gave me the conviction that this is the place for me."

Should the "to my hallway..." clause begin with "to" or "and"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tushar, this is well-written overall. But are you sure "recitation" is the word you want here? Recitation means presenting memorized materials orally, which doesn't make perfect sense alongside "about songwriting." "Lecture" makes better sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace 'to' with 'and' here would not be grammatically incorrect, but you would lose the rhythmic and rhetorical impact of the "from... to... to..." format of your sentence.

Personally, I'd leave it as it is.

Regarding another stylistic issue, I would replace

> ...gave me the conviction that this is the place for me.

with the more elegant

> ...convinced me that this was the place for me.

(Notice that I've also replaced *is* with *was* here, to match the tense of the other verbs in the sentence.)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I'll leave it as is and I appreciate the additional style suggestion. One more question: you mentiond you changed the tense from is to was. Does that detract from the overall message that I STILL believe this IS the place for me? Does it lead the reader to believe that I was convinced some time in the past, but something may have changed?

Comment: @TusharGarg - The use of 'was' places the *moment of the narrator's realization* slightly further back in the past in relation to their present; but 'is' can certainly still be used instead; indeed, that might be the better choice if the narrator is still in the place they mention, and/or if the events referred to took place very recently in relation to their present moment.